# How to have a subject in RxSwift push values to itself without creating an infinite loop

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have a UITableView, which I want to put into an editing state if certain conditions are met. The primary way to toggling edit is through an edit button.

So the view elements I have are

```
let tableView = UITableView()
let editButton = UIButton()
```

And whether the tableView should be in editing mode is fed from:

```
let editing = BehaviorSubject(value: false)
```

Which will be hooked up to the tableView using something like:

```
editing.subscribeNext { isEditing in
  tableView.setEditing(isEditing, animated: true)
}
```

When the edit button is tapped, I want that to push a new value to `editing`, that is the negation of the most recent value sent to `editing`. The most recently value may have been set by a tap on `editButton`, or it may have come from somewhere else.

I don't understand how to combine the stream for the button press with the stream for `editing` in such a way that allows this without an infinite loop e.g.

```
Obervable.combineLatest(editButton.rx_tap.asObservable(), editing) { _, isEditing in
  editing.onNext(!isEditing)
}
```

I'm aware that the tableView has an `editing` property, but I don't want to rely on that as I am looking for a more general solution that I can re-use elsewhere. I'm also not looking to track the value of isEditing in an instance var, or even as a Variable(), as I am looking for a stateless, stream based solution (if this is at all possible).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from the RxSwift GitHub issues forum I've now worked it out :). The key was `withLatestFrom`. I've included an example of this below in case it will help anyone else. `editButton` is the primary way to trigger editing mode on or off, and I've included an event sent via `tableView.rx_itemSelected` as an additional input example (in this case, I want editing to end any time an item is selected).

```
let isEditing = BehaviorSubject(value: false)
let tableView = UITableView()
let editButton = UIButton()

tableView.rx_itemSelected
  .map { _ in false }
  .bindTo(isEditing)

editButton.rx_tap.withLatestFrom(isEditing)
  .map { !$0 }
  .bindTo(isEditing)

isEditing.subscribeNext { editing in
  tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
}
```

Note: This solution sends `.Next(false)` to `isEditing` every time an item is selected, even if the table isn't currently in editing mode. If you feel this is a bad thing, and want to filter `rx_itemSelected` to only send `.Next(false)` if the table is actually in editing mode, you could probably do this using a combination of `withLatestFrom` and `filter`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

What if you define `editing` as a `Variable` instead of a `BehaviourSubject`. A `Variable` cannot error out which makes sense in this case. The declaration would look like this:

```
let editing = Variable(value: false)
```

You could subscribe to a button tap and change the value of `editing` to the negated current one:

```
editButton.rx_tap.asObservable().subscribeNext { editing.value = !editing.value }
```

With changing the `value` property of `editing` this method is called

```
editing.subscribeNext { isEditing in
    tableView.setEditing(isEditing, animated: true)
}
```

All of this is not tested, but might lead you in the right direction for the right solution.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion! It's definitely possible using Variable, but once you are using Variable, you aren't really combining streams to make this happen. Instead you are introducing state and using that (much the same as if I was tracking isEditing in an instance var). As I said I'm looking for a stream based solution. I'll edit my question to make it a bit clearer!